# Which villains count as season 1/2 villains?

Tags: achievements, sentinels-of-the-multiverse

I decided to do some achievement hunting, with Classic Champion as my main target. This requires completing the 20 season 1 & 2 villains in classic mode on Ultimate difficulty. However, there are a lot more than 20 villains available to choose from!

Which villains count as season 1 and 2 villains? Do I need to defeat their variants as well (assuming any of them have variants)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The following 20 classic mode villains are from Seasons 1 or 2:

1. Ambuscade (S1: Mini-Pack 1)
2. The Chairman (S1: Rook City)
3. The Matriarch (S1: Rook City)
4. Plague Rat (S1: Rook City)
5. Spite (S1: Rook City)
6. Akash'bhuta (S1: Infernal Relics)
7. Apostate (S1: Infernal Relics)
8. The Ennead (S1: Infernal Relics)
9. Gloomweaver (S1: Infernal Relics)
10. Miss Information (S1: Mini-Pack 2)
11. The Dreamer (S1: Shattered Timelines)
12. Iron Legacy (S1: Shattered Timelines)
13. Kismet (S1: Shattered Timelines)
14. La Capitan (S1: Shattered Timelines)
15. Deadline (S1: Wrath of the Cosmos)
16. Infinitor (S1: Wrath of the Cosmos)
17. Kaargra Warfang (S1: Wrath of the Cosmos)
18. Progeny (S1: Wrath of the Cosmos)
19. Wager Master (S1: Mini-Pack 3)
20. Chokepoint (S2: Mini-Pack 4)

Variants do *not* need to be defeated to get credit for the achievements.

All team mode villains are associated with Season 2, and so the achievements for defeating Season 2 team mode villains effectively require defeating all team mode villains.